# installing cloudant database on suse

Tags: python, cloudant

we are planning to run IBM CLoudant local on openSUSE 42.

running following command

```
cast system install -p password -db
```

as https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.1.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.install.doc/topics/appendix_offline_python_dependencies.html

it is throwing following error

```
Node Type Package Name Version Status --------- ------------ ------- ------ 
ERROR:cast.check:'suse42' Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/opt/cloudant/cast/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cast/suse_check.py", line 66, in packages node_pkgs =self.pkgs[self.os_identifier][node] KeyError: 'suse42' 
INFO:cast.system:Updating the repository cache. 
ERROR:cast.commands.cmd_system:'suse42' Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/opt/cloudant/cast/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cast/commands/cmd_system.py", line 151, in install system.install(dbnode, lbnode, password, config) 
File "/opt/cloudant/cast/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cast/system.py", line 52, in install self._install_pkgs(dbnode, lbnode) 
File "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this page:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.1.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.install.doc/topics/clinstall_software_reqs.html
under "Supported architecture and platforms" it says:

> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 12

So I think the issue is that it's an unsupported version of SUSE Linux.

That said, the file `/opt/cloudant/cast/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cast/suse_check.py` is written in python and could presumably be edited to allow the version you are trying to install on. Since it hasn't actually been tested on that platform, however, you will be on your own at that point.

Comment: its openSUSE 42.3 (x86_64) VERSION = 42.3 CODENAME = Malachite and openSUSE Leap 42.3 shares source code from SUSE Linux Enterprise (SLE) 12 Service Pack (SP) 3.

Comment: It may share the source code, but unfortunately, the installer doesn't know that.